# Can I have overlapping elements in Android?

Tags: java, android

I want to have different Views based on an action that takes place.

My question:

1) From a layout perspective, how do I need to set up my views so that I can toggle between a TextView and a Chronometer?

Answer (score 1):

This question is tricky to answer because it's not very specific, and the best approach could depend on exactly what you're trying to do. However I'm just going to assume that you have a single `Activity` at present, and you simply want one `View` or another kind of `View` to be visible, perhaps depending on the result of some menu selection, or something.

The way I interpret your question, to make it more specific, is basically "how can I dynamically add / remove `View`s or make them invisible / visible".

To make child `Views` appear and disappear there are a number of simple approaches you could take:

1. Remove and add `Views` to the parent `View` as and when you need to, using `addView()` and `removeView()` calls on the parent containing `ViewGroup` (which might for example be the a containing `LinearLayout`). When you add the `View`, you'll want to pass appropriate layout parameters for its positioning, etc.
2. You could use `setVisibility()` on a `View` to hide it or make it visible. (Perhaps setting the width and height to zero might have the same effect.)
3. ... and possibly many other possibilities, depending on what exactly you want to achieve. For example, if you want to show two somewhat different compositions of UI depending on action chosen, you might want to just use separate `Activity` classes altogether, or you might choose to flip between layouts using a `ViewFlipper`, and so on.